# Error: container has not been made global - how to solve?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aurelia

I'm trying to get the Firebase Reactive Collection (Sync database) to work with the Aurelia-Firebase plugin. I'm using the following code to set a reference to the database:

```
// collections/table.js

import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ReactiveCollection} from 'aurelia-firebase';

export class TableCollection extends ReactiveCollection {
    constructor() {
        super('tables');
    }
}
```

And the following code to see if the reference is working:

```
// table-overview.js

import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {TableCollection} from './collections/table';

@inject(TableCollection)
export class TableOverview {

    constructor(collection:TableCollection){
        alert(collection);
    }
}
```

Upon executing my code, I get the following stack trace

```
------------------------------------------------
inner error: Error: Container has not been made global
at Error (native)
at TableCollection.ReactiveCollection (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/github/pulsarblow/aurelia-firebase@0.2.1-beta/collection.js:27:108)
at new TableCollection (http://localhost:3000/src/collections/table.js!transpiled:25:87)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:334:14)
at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:309:168)
at Container.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:557:25)
at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
at Container._get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:502:41)
at Container.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:491:28)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:339:33)
at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:309:168)
at Container.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:557:25)
at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
at Container.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:494:23)
at eval (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.1.1/aurelia-templating.js:3899:73)
at Error (native)
at TableCollection.ReactiveCollection (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/github/pulsarblow/aurelia-firebase@0.2.1-beta/collection.js:27:108)
at new TableCollection (http://localhost:3000/src/collections/table.js!transpiled:25:87)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:334:14)
at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:309:168)
at Container.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:557:25)
at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
at Container._get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:502:41)
at Container.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:491:28)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:339:33)
at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:309:168)
at Container.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:557:25)
at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
at Container.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:494:23)
at eval (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.1.1/aurelia-templating.js:3899:73)
at new AggregateError (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1.1.1/aurelia-pal.js:20:13)
at Container.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:559:15)
at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
at Container._get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:502:41)
at Container.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:491:28)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:339:33)
at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:309:168)
at Container.invoke (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:557:25)
at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
at Container.get (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:494:23)
at eval (http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.1.1/aurelia-templating.js:3899:73)
```

I've been breaking my head over this and I really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that is immediately apparent is the plugin you are using is almost 1 year out of date. If you look in its `package.json` file you can see it is referencing beta Aurelia libraries and not the latest release candidate ones.

Looking at the source code, you can see the error message you are getting here: https://github.com/PulsarBlow/aurelia-firebase/blob/master/src/collection.js#L13 -- I think because two different versions of the Dependency Injection library are being used, the containers are different and therefore, there is no instance registered.

I would honestly just install Firebase manually and use it that way by installing it via Jspm: `jspm install firebase` should do the trick for you.

Comment: I have opened an issue at the repository and moved back to angular until Aurelia has a proper integration with firebase. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to move back to Angular. Adding in Firebase without using a plugin is so easy.

Comment: I have tried to do so but I fail to understand where to put my config and how to "import" my firebase instance in the other Aurelia classes... can you give me a clue? :-)

Comment: I just so happened to have recently open sourced an Aurelia project using Firebase via it's CDN script which you can see [here](https://github.com/Vheissu/pokego.run-public/blob/master/index.html#L192) and then I just reference the `firebase` global variable throughout my app as normal without needing to import anything, etc.

Comment: Great to hear @RobinClaes I am glad I was able to help.