# Firebase database: Cannot loop through .push()'ed array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aurelia

After pushing some objects to my Firebase sync database, and retrieving them, I get the following array:

```
(index)                 products    time

-KNOR5bBgf1ilVehk7BI    Array[1]    "22:26:47"
-KNORdccyvXat8wsP0SF    Array[2]    "22:29:10"
```

When using Firebase's .push(), Firebase generates a random ID such as the one above.

After trying to loop them with Aurelia (using repeat.for)

```
<order-details repeat.for="order of bill.orders" order.bind="order"></order>
```

I get the following error

```
aurelia-task-queue.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCollectionObserver' of null_observeCollection @ repeat.js:152itemsChanged @ repeat.js:99selfSubscriber @ aurelia-templating.js:3122call @ aurelia-templating.js:2989flushMicroTaskQueue @ aurelia-task-queue.js:117(anonymous function) @ aurelia-task-queue.js:61
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with the keys (indexes), because **before** I used an incremental index (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) and it worked perfectly fine.
EDIT: I have experimented with other keys such as "0" and 2 and they don't work either. Seems Aurelia only knows how to repeat through arrays that start with 0???

Why is this happening?

Comment: I am curious. How are you using Firebase, is it just the script tag via the CDN or are you using a plugin? Because I am using Firebase in my public app [here](https://github.com/Vheissu/pokego.run-public/blob/master/src/home.ts#L91) which isn't via a plugin, just the Firebase provided CDN script and it works fine. I get the data in my viewmodel and push it, also using unique ID's.

Comment: Hi Dwayne, you helped me in another question too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361421/error-container-has-not-been-made-global-how-to-solve

I'm not using a plugin, just the script tag.

Does your firebase data also have these unique firebase ids?

Comment: @DwayneCharrington , you can find the full code of my project here: https://github.com/rclaes1995/aurelia-register

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use repeat.for to loop over an object instead of an array. You'll need to convert it to an array to repeat over the properties of the object. See this article: http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/08/iterating-objects-using-repeat-for-in-aurelia/

When you changed them to 0,1,2 javascript reads it as:

```
orders[0]
orders[1]
```

Javascript sees that as an array.

What you have is this:

```
orders['-KNOR5bBgf1ilVehk7BI']
orders['-KNORdccyvXat8wsP0SF']
```

Javascript sees this as an object. You can't loop over an object's properties without a value-converter using Aurelia's repeat.for.

Since it has to pass through a value-converter you may need to setup a binding singler to tell the repeat.for to update. You can find a simple example of that here: [Update Aurelia observed property on change to containing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759154/update-aurelia-observed-property-on-change-to-containing-array)

Comment: Thank you so much!